# Azure Dashboard status 'Limited' can't access any websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

2 of my subscriptions are showing 'Limited' in the status column, and I can't click through to their individual dashboards. I have a number of subs, and all is fine for the rest of them.

I have checked the status page, and it says that all is fine:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#current

My accounts seem fine. They are paid up and active, and are showing as 'Active'

Can anyone help? I was sent here for their support page, so I'm assuming that there are Azure staff on stack overflow.

Comment: The same story. 2 sites are limited. 1 of these is unavailable.

Comment: upd: seems like the problem was fixed for me, everything works.

Comment: Yup. Seems like their status update page was lying!